# Localized descriptions for Blend

Tags: c#, wpf, localization, categories

I'm working on a custom control in WPF. My control has a lot of Properties to set by the User. I'm creating the descriptions by following code:

```
[Description("Desc"), Category("Category")]
```

Is there any solution to set the Category not as string? If I'm setting a string like "Common Properties" and working then on a german IDE I'm getting a new section named "Common Properties", but I want to have it in "Allgemeine Eigenschaften", not in a seperate section.

Comment: That's what resource files are for?

Comment: You mean I'm having to add category names in each language?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as McKay states, resource files are what's needed in this case.
An approach similar to this would work: 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29495/Binding-and-Using-Friendly-Enums-in-WPF

Use the LocalizedDescription instead of Description and a type converter on the DataGridColumn Header to convert from the resource ID to the string for the current local.

Of course, there are several ways to do this sort of stuff and this approach may not suit what you're project.